# CSS on hover expand element in left direction

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `button` with a `:hover` effect works fine when `padding-right` is used to `float` the `button` text towards the right and a quick reverse of this effect should result in the `button` text floating towards the left but that's where the problem lies as the padding is still being added to the right of the element even though `padding-left` was specified.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>button</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .ButtonLeft, .ButtonRight{
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0.5%;
      padding: 0.652em 1.5em;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 1.5em;

      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.75);
      background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.0)),
        to(rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.75)));
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .ButtonLeft span{
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      left: -0.05em;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .ButtonLeft span:before{
      content: '\00ab';
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
      left: -0.05em;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .ButtonLeft:hover span{
      padding-left: 1.7em;
      left: -1.5em;
    }
    .ButtonLeft:hover span:before{
      left: -1.5em;
      opacity: 1;
      color: inherit;
    }

    .ButtonRight span{
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      right: -0.05em;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .ButtonRight span:after{
      content: '\00bb';
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
      right: -0.05em;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .ButtonRight:hover span{
      padding-right: 1.7em;
      right: -1.5em;
    }
    .ButtonRight:hover span:after{
      right: -1.5em;
      opacity: 1;
      color: inherit;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
 <button class="ButtonLeft"><span>i am lefty</span></button>
 <br>
 <br>
 <button class="ButtonRight"><span>i am right</span></button>
</body>
```

here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobbyaxe61/tv1fw30q/1/), 
any help, hints or explanation on what am doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: am trying to make `.ButtonLeft` grow/expand the element towards the left the same way `.ButtonRight` expands its own element towards the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the padding is still being added to the right of the element even
>   though padding left was specified.

This because you did not set the `width` of the buttons.

You just need to add a `width` in the `.ButtonLeft, .ButtonRight` so that when you add `padding` left or right it will follow the specified padding.

```css
.ButtonLeft, .ButtonRight{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 0.652em 1.5em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  width: 15em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.75);
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear, left top, left bottom,
    from(rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.0)),
    to(rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.75)));
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.ButtonLeft span{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonLeft span:before{
  content: '\00ab';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonLeft:hover span{
  padding-left: 1.7em;
  left: -3.5em;
}
.ButtonLeft:hover span:before{
  left: -1.5em;
  opacity: 1;
  color: inherit;
}

.ButtonRight span{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonRight span:after{
  content: '\00bb';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  right: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonRight:hover span{
  padding-right: 1.7em;
  right: -3.5em;
}
.ButtonRight:hover span:after{
  right: -1.5em;
  opacity: 1;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button class="ButtonLeft"><span>i am lefty</span></button>
   <br>
   <br>
  <button class="ButtonRight"><span>i am right</span></button>
```

---

> it cancels out the expansion of the buttons towards right or left side on
>   hover

To make the left `button` to expand to the left you need to make it `float:right` so the `padding` you added will be added in the left side. Also, add a `.btnContainer` and specified its `width` so that the `button` will not `float` on the right most of the screen.

Then add `white-space:nowrap;` to the `span` so the text will stay in one line and will not wrap.

```css
.btnContainer{
  width:8em;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.ButtonLeft{
float:right;
}

.ButtonLeft, .ButtonRight{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 0.652em 1.5em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.75);
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear, left top, left bottom,
    from(rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.0)),
    to(rgba(0, 10, 26, 0.75)));
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.ButtonLeft span{
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonLeft span:before{
  content: '\00ab';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonLeft:hover span{
  padding-left: 1.7em;
  left: -1.5em;
}
.ButtonLeft:hover span:before{
  left: -1.5em;
  opacity: 1;
  color: inherit;
}

.ButtonRight span{
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonRight span:after{
  content: '\00bb';
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  right: -0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.ButtonRight:hover span{
  padding-right: 1.7em;
  right: -1.5em;
}
.ButtonRight:hover span:after{
  right: -1.5em;
  opacity: 1;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">
     <button class="ButtonLeft"><span>i am lefty</span></button>
  </div>
 <div class="btnContainer">
    <button class="ButtonRight"><span>i am right</span></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you, yes this works fine but cancels out the expansion of the buttons towards right or left side on hover

Comment: i think maybe css cant show this effect the way it should be maybe because elements are usually aligned to the left by default? or is the display as `inline-block` the problem i have tried other display type's went as far as `flex` :(

Comment: if there is no other fix i will accept your answer as it solved the problem half way thanks alot.

Comment: @BobbyAxe I understand now, Please see my updated answer and hope it helps.

Comment: yesss!! had to add a little more adjustments but your update works perfectly thanks deeply appreciate the help. :)

Comment: @BobbyAxe Cool. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following fix your problem?

```
.ButtonLeft:hover span{
    padding-left: 1.7em;
    /* left: -1.5em; */
 }

.ButtonRight:hover span{
     padding-right: 1.7em;
     /* right: -1.5em; */
}
```

Comment: am sorry but it didn't fix it, i tried both commented and un-commented and even together. :( also does display as inline-block have any effect on padding-left?

Comment: perhaps I am misunderstanding the effect you are trying to get. In your original code, everything works as expected, I mean if you check dev tools (set :hover to `.ButtonLeft`) you'll see that padding-left is applied.

Comment: yes it's applied, am just trying to make .ButtonLeft work/slide text and grow element the same way .ButtonRight slides text and grows its element but towards the left

Comment: but the part of the button that grows is the right part in both cases

Comment: @IP_ he wanted to expand the element to the left when hovered